# Marking 3U board size on a 6U board in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I have an Altium design of a board which is 6U size. I want to mark 3U size on it using some line-drawing. As I don't have hands-on on Altium so struggling to do it.

How to know the size in Altium as I need to draw 100mm x 160mm 3U board?
How to draw line for marking the above size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Altium 17.1:

- View/Board Insight - check Heads-up display: this displays the position of your cursor
- Grids - Set global grid: you can set the snap grid to mm-s to makes positioning easier
- Draw the lines on the layer you want (probably a mechanical layer)
- You can also set the line coordinate in the line properties (double click, or right click, properties)
- also you can use Place/Dimension/Linear to measure and display distances